# Do PHP closures not have access to parnt function parameters?

Tags: closures, php-5.3, php-closures

I've been writing some code for PHP 5.3, and I wanted to do something similar to the code I'm showing below. I expect this code to print 'hellohello', but it prints 'hello' instead, and an error.

It appears the $inner closure does not have access to the outer function's parameters. Is this normal behavior? Is it a PHP bug? I can't see how that could be considered correct behavior...

```
<?php

function outer($var) {

  print $var;

  $inner = function() {
    print $var;
  };
  $inner();
}

outer('hello');
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature :P A badly designed feature...

Comment: Also, it's not just the parameters - it's any variables local to `outer()` as well.

Comment: Wow. That's pretty sad. Thank you for the answer(s), though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `use` keyword. See [this](http://www.slideshare.net/sebastian_bergmann/php-53-new-language-features/19) for more details.

[Wikipedia has some explanation of this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#5.3_and_newer):

```
function getAdder($x)
{
    return function ($y) use ($x) {
        return $x + $y;
     };
}

$adder = getAdder(8);
echo $adder(2); // prints "10"
```

> Here, getAdder() function creates a closure using parameter $x (keyword "use" forces getting variable from context), which takes additional argument $y and returns it to the caller.

So, to make your example work the way you want it to:

```
<?php

function outer($var) {

  print $var;

  $inner = function() use ($var) {
    print $var;
  };
  $inner();
}

outer('hello');
```

Comment: Thank you, Sir. That is pretty nasty!

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the $inner function doesn't have the scope to access $var

**Try this**

```
function outer($var) {

  print $var;

  $inner = function($var) {
    print $var;
  };
  $inner($var);
}

outer('hello');
```